# Excel formula issue for excluding matching fileds

Tags: excel

Hello I am using the current formula to count the total for each column that has A reference number in the field. However  Some of the columns may have Identical Reference numbers to other column. Example column G13 may contain the same Reference number as column K13, also O13 may have the same number as S13. I only want to count the number once if it has multiple matching numbers.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($G$13,ROW($B$13:$B$500)-ROW($G$13),,1)),--
($G$13:$G$500<>"Not Assigned")+($K$13:$K$500<>"Not Assigned")+
($O$13:$O$500<>"Not Assigned")+($S$13:$S$500<>"Not Assigned")+
($W$13:$W$500<>"Not Assigned")+($AA$13:$AA$500<>"Not Assigned")+
($AE$13:$AE$500<>"Not Assigned")+($AI$13:$AI$500<>"Not Assigned")+
($AM$13:$AM$500<>"Not Assigned")+($AQ$13:$AQ$500<>"Not Assigned"))
```

Comment: I think we're going to need to see some sample data and what the results of this formula would look like given that sample data (desired results). Your text-only explanation is insufficient. For instance... I don't know what "Reference number" means, but perhaps if I see a sample of what that means I will better understand.

Comment: The reference number is just a field that contain a Number associated to a policy, example 56-0218-80683.

Comment: I have an image of the data but note sure how to upload the image.

Comment: If you can upload the image somewhere public, then one of us with more Rep points can edit it into your question.

Comment: Better yet use a site like [this one](http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and copy your excel data into it. You might consider adding an extra header row/column to put in the column and row numbers since this is excel. Anyway... paste it in there and copy out the bottom box. Paste it into you question, highlight what you pasted, and hit the code format button at the top.

Comment: Below is Some data. 

Employee Name | Total  | Date  | Client Name | Reference #1   |  Type #1  |  Category 1 | Reference #2  | Type #2  | Category 2  | Reference #3   | Type #3  | Category 3  | 
+===============+
| Joe Smith | 50  | 1/8/2018 | ASE | 56-0318-5556 | NBP  | 4 Veh Business Use | 56-0218-10814 | Input NC | 4 Veh Ann Mi/Odom | 56-0218-10814  | Input NC  | 4 Veh Add/Rem/Repl |  --+----
| Cathy Smith   | 50  | 1/8/2018 | ASE | 56-0218-80683  | NBP | 4 Veh Title Owner  | 56-0318-66699 | Input NC | 2 CCD Driver Info | Not Assigned   | Not Assigned  | Not Assigned   | ---+--

Comment: Again the issue is I am trying to Determine how many "Input NC" (the type field) there are per Policy (Unique Reference number). Some people can have several "Input NC" for one Reference number, so I only want to count the reference number once but I want to count each "Input NC" (Type Field). Example I may have one reference number and three "Input NC"  and another Reference number with one "Input NC" for Joe.

Comment: Data above starts with header then the Data. Thank again all.